# Table/Report Format Using PDFBox

Tags: java, string, pdf, pdfbox

I am having formatting issues with PDF Box. My goal is to print a PDF in table style format as a report. The content format will be similar to

```
Name Code Description Value
```

I retrieve my DB result set and have a List of Java objects. I extract the required information and I format them as as a list of strings as  below. I cycle thru the objects, construct a string and add to an arrayList. The idea being I create a list of Strings of the exact same length/style to enforce formatting in pdf.

[Code Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805953/java-string-manipulation-add-spaces-or-substring)

```
for(MyObject obj: dbresults){
   //format as below and add to list
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);
formatter.format("%-25.25s", "This is some text with more than 25 characters.");

formatter.format("%-25.25s", "Some text with less.");

formatter.format("%-25.25s", "Some other text.");

System.out.println(formatter.toString());
```

Output:

```
|This is some text with mo|Some text with less.     |Some other text.         |
```

I print out this list multiple times to screen :) and via System.out or logger the format is exactly as I expect, even blocks.

However when I send to PDFBox to print to file the format gets 'corrupted' and the 'table format' is not honoured. I pass in 100 and 700 as x,y co-ords.

[Code Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598099/how-to-insert-a-linefeed-with-pdfbox-drawstrin)

```
    private void printMultipleLines(
    PDPageContentStream contentStream,
    List<String> lines,
    float x,
    float y) throws IOException {
  if (lines.size() == 0) {
    return;
  }
  final int numberOfLines = lines.size();
  final float fontHeight = getFontHeight();

  contentStream.beginText();
  contentStream.appendRawCommands(fontHeight + " TL\n");
  contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( x, y);
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    contentStream.drawString(lines.get(i));
    if (i < numberOfLines - 1) {
      contentStream.appendRawCommands("T*\n");
    }
  }
  contentStream.endText();
}
```

To get the height of the font you can use this command:

```
fontHeight = font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000 * fontSize;
```

Sample List for printing: This is how it looks after using java formatter class when printing to screen, All looks good, but when i print to PDFBox the format is not honoured

```
Tom Thumb         555-ddd   Good     23
Tom Thumb         666-ggg   Good     45
CHARLES DICKENS   777-jjj   Good     32
CHARLES DICKENS   666-hhh   Bad      11
W Yeats           888-hhh   Ok       12
R Whitely         444-999   Terrible 44
```

PDF output looks like

```
Tom Thumb         555-ddd   Good     23
Tom Thumb         666-ggg   Good     45
CHARLES DICKENS       777-jjj   Good     32
CHARLES DICKENS       666-hhh   Bad      11
W Yeats           888-hhh   Ok       12
R Whitely          444-999   Terrible 44
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Please supply a sample PDF, e.g. as google or dropbox public share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do you use monospaced fonts in the PDF (as Courier) ?
It would explain that you get good output in console and a bad one in PDF

regards

Comment: (ahhhhhhhhhhhhhh -- penny dropping) I was using Helveitca! That might be it. I'll give it a go